# Modelling Immerman–Szelepcsényi in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, graph, complexity

I am trying to model the proof of Immerman–Szelepcsényi Theorem with Haskell since it heavily uses non-determinism. An explanation of what the point of this is can be found [here](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/a-haskell-aware-explanation-of/).

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State

type NonDet a = [a]

type NonDetState s a = StateT s [] a

type Vertex = Int

-- represent the graph as an adjacency list
-- or equivalently, a nondeterministic computation
-- that returns the next vertex given the current
getNextVertex :: Vertex -> NonDet Vertex
getNextVertex = undefined

-- is there a path from `source` to `target` in `bound` steps
guessPath :: Int -> Vertex -> Vertex -> NonDetState Vertex ()
guessPath bound source target = do
  put source
  nonDeterministicWalk bound
    where
      nonDeterministicWalk bound = do
        guard (bound >= 0)
        v <- get
        if v == target
        then return ()
        else do
          w <- lift $ getNextVertex v
          put w
          nonDeterministicWalk (bound - 1)

-- if you knew the number of vertices reachable from the source
-- use that to certify that target is not reachable
certifyUnreachAux :: [Vertex] -> Int -> Vertex -> Vertex -> NonDetState Int ()
certifyUnreachAux vertices c source target = do
  put 0
  forM_ vertices $ \v -> do
    -- guess whether the vertex v is reachable or not
    guess <- lift [True, False]
    if (not guess || v == target)
    -- if the vertex v is not reachable or is the target
    -- then just move on to the next one
    then return ()
    else do
     -- otherwise verify that the vertex is indeed reachable
     guessPath (length vertices) source v
     counter <- get
     put (counter + 1)
  counter <- get
  guard (counter == c)
  return ()


-- figure out the number of vertices reachable from source
-- in `steps` steps
countReachable :: [Vertex] -> Int -> Vertex -> NonDet Int
countReachable vertices steps source = do
  if steps <= 0
  then return 1
  else do
    previouslyReachable <- countReachable vertices (steps - 1) source
    evalStateT (countReachableInduct vertices previouslyReachable steps source) (0, 0, False)

-- figuring out how many vertices are reachable in (i+1) steps
-- given the number of vertices reachable in i steps
countReachableInduct :: [Vertex] -> Int -> Int -> Vertex -> NonDetState (Int, Int, Bool) Int
countReachableInduct vertices previouslyReachable steps source = do
  -- initialize the counters to 0
  put (0, 0, False)
  forM_ vertices $ \v -> do
    -- set the first counter to 0
    -- and unset the flag that says you have
    -- checked that v is a neighbor of u or u itself
    (previousCount, currentCount, b) <- get
    put (0, currentCount, False)
    forM_ vertices $ \u -> do
       -- guess if u reachable from the source in (steps - 1) steps
       guess <- lift [True, False]
       if not guess
       -- if not, then we can move ahead to the next u
       then return ()
       else do
       -- since we guessed that u is reachable,
       -- we should verify it
       lift $ evalStateT (guessPath (steps - 1) source u) 0
       (previousCount, currentCount, b) <- get
       put ((previousCount + 1), currentCount, b)
       if (u == v)
       then do
          (previousCount, currentCount, _) <- get
          put (previousCount, currentCount, True)
       else do
          neighbor <- lift $ getNextVertex u
          if (u == neighbor)
          then do
            (previousCount, currentCount, _) <- get
            put (previousCount, currentCount, True)
          else
            -- if v is neither u nor a neighbor of u,
            -- we just move to the second iteration
            return ()
    guard (previousCount == previouslyReachable)
    (previousCount, currentCount, b) <- get
    -- if v was at most distance 1 from u, which
    -- we verfied to be a vertex reachable in
    -- (steps - 1) steps, then v is reachable
    -- in steps steps
    put (previousCount, (currentCount + if b then 1 else 0), b)
  (_, currentCount, _) <- get
  return currentCount

-- finally put all the methods together and show that
-- target is unreachable from source
certifyUnreach :: [Vertex] -> Vertex -> Vertex -> NonDet ()
certifyUnreach vertices source target = do
  c <- countReachable vertices (length vertices) source
  evalStateT (certifyUnreachAux vertices c source target) 0
```

I'd like general comments on how I could improve coding style. One particular thing is the awkward use of `get` and `put` to get the three counters but update one of them. I would like to know how this can be done more elegantly with lenses.

Comment: `guard (previousCount == previouslyReachable)` <- did you mean to use the previousCount defined in the line after `-- checked that v is a neighbor of u or u itself`?

Comment: I meant to use the latest value of ```previousCount```. So you are correct, I should have used a new ```get``` to get that value

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to try to build/compile/test a full new version of your code, but I think I can still suggest ways to improve it.

You asked about using lenses to improve the `get >>= put` pattern you're using. I do think lenses have a place here (I'm not experienced with them), but they're not the first thing you need.

- Writing a expression of type `State (Int, Int, Bool)` is smelly. Tuples aren't *bad*, but they don't *denote their own meaning*. Which `Int` is which? What does the `Bool` represent? Also, for a triplet you can't use the convenient `fst` and `snd`. So: Introduce a record type for this state.
- Very often (I'm tempted to say "most of the time") one should use `gets` and `modify` instead of `get` and `put`. For example (in tuple syntax for now) instead of a `get` followed by a `put`, you would just write `modify \(c1, c2, _) -> (c1, c2, True)`.

If you combine the above, you'll get something that's idiomatic and reads clearly without additional commentary. But it'll be a little verbose; you'll probably start getting warnings about line-length. This is where lenses help: You want a concise way to build the record-manipulating functions to pass to `modify`. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38086493/10135377) an example I found quickly, and there are lots of complete tutorials around.

All that said, I think some of your functions aren't really using (or don't need) the abstraction of the `State` monad (transformer). Notice how these functions start by writing their own state immediately, or they only write immediately before recursing, or when they're called, the resulting monadic value is immediately `eval`uated, or that none of your functions are using the *same* state type. I think `guessPath` and `certifyUnreachAux` should be re-written as stateless. `countReachableInduct` makes sense with a statefull body, but move the evaluation inside the function so the statefull-ness isn't part of the function's type (and save your self the initial `put` and terminal `get` using `execState`).

On the other hand, I think the abstraction of a global `getNextVertex :: Vertex -> NonDet Vertex` is highly suspicious. This implies that a single graph will be locked in at compile time? Looking at [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immerman%E2%80%93Szelepcs%C3%A9nyi_theorem), that *might* be consistent with the intended proof, but if not then you might lift stuff into a [Reader](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was going to use lens, but everything worked out mundanely. :/

```
-- is there a path from `source` to `target` in `bound` steps
guessPath :: Int -> Vertex -> Vertex -> NonDet ()
guessPath bound source target = nonDeterministicWalk source bound where
  nonDeterministicWalk v bound = do
    guard $ bound >= 0
    unless (v == target) $ do
      w <- getNextVertex v
      nonDeterministicWalk w (bound - 1)

-- figure out the number of vertices reachable from source
-- in `steps` steps
countReachable :: [Vertex] -> Int -> Vertex -> NonDet Int
countReachable vertices steps source = if steps <= 0 then return 1 else do
  previouslyReachable <- countReachable vertices (steps - 1) source
  fmap sum $ for vertices $ \v -> (`evalStateT` False) $ do
    -- the state flag witnesses that 
    -- v has at most distance 1 from u
    guard . (== previouslyReachable) . sum =<< vertices `for` \u ->
      -- guess if u reachable from the source in (steps - 1) steps
      return 0 <|> 1 <$ do -- if not, then we can move ahead to the next u
        -- since we guessed that u is reachable, we should verify it
        guessPath (steps - 1) source u
        if u == v then put True
        else do
          neighbor <- lift $ getNextVertex u
          when (u == neighbor) $ put True
          -- if v is neither u nor a neighbor of u,
          -- we just move to the second iteration
    -- if v was at most distance 1 from u, which
    -- we verfied to be a vertex reachable in
    -- (steps - 1) steps, then v is reachable
    -- in steps steps
    gets $ bool 0 1

-- finally put all the methods together and show that
-- target is unreachable from source
certifyUnreach :: [Vertex] -> Vertex -> Vertex -> NonDet ()
certifyUnreach vertices source target = do
  c <- countReachable vertices (length vertices) source
  guard . (== c) . sum =<< vertices `for` \v ->
    -- guess whether the vertex v is reachable and not the target
    return 0 <|> 1 <$ do
      -- verify that the vertex is indeed reachable and not the target
      guard $ v /= target
      guessPath (length vertices) source v
```